# Выводит одну запись вместо всех

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Здравствуйте. В чем может быть проблема: выводит одну запись из базы вместо всех. Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не найти ошибку.

```
<?php

require( 'global.php' );
require( CWD . '/includes/framework_start.php' );
compile_hook( 'singers_start' );

if (( !$id && $op != 'letter' )) {
    $qr2 = db_query( 'select * from songs_cats where active=1 order by ord asc' );

    if (db_num( $qr2 )) {
        open_table( $phrases['the_cats'] );
        $c = 0;
        print '<table width=100%><tr>';

        while ($data = db_fetch( $qr2 )) {
            if ($c == $settings['songs_cells']) {
                print '  </tr><tr>';
                $c = 0;
            }

            ++$c;
            print '<td align=center>' . print_link( print_image( get_image( $data['img'], 'images/folder.gif' ), $data['name'] ) . ( '' . '<br>' . $data['name'] ), cat_url( $data['id'], $data['page_name'], $data['name'] ), $data['name'] ) . '</td>';
        }

        print '</tr></table>';
        close_table(  );
    } else {
        print '' . '<center> ' . $phrases['err_no_cats'] . ' </center>';
    }
} else {
    if ($letter) {
        $qr = db_query( 'select songs_singers.*,songs_cats.name as cat_name , songs_cats.id as cat_id , songs_cats.page_name as cat_page_name from songs_singers,songs_cats where songs_singers.active=1 and songs_singers.cat=songs_cats.id and songs_cats.active=1 and songs_singers.name like "' . db_escape( $letter ) . '%" order by songs_singers.name asc' );
        $title = htmlspecialchars( $letter );
    } else {
        $qr = db_query( '' . 'select songs_singers.* from songs_singers,songs_cats where songs_singers.active=1 and songs_singers.cat=songs_cats.id and songs_cats.active=1 and songs_cats.id="' . $id . '" order by  songs_singers.name asc ' );
        $data_title = db_qr_fetch( '' . 'select name from songs_cats where id="' . $id . '" and active=1' );
        $title = $data_title['name'];
    }

    if (db_num( $qr )) {
        open_table( $title );

        if (( $settings['singers_groups'] && !$letter )) {
            unset( $data_arr );
            unset( $data_arr2 );

            if ($data = db_fetch( $qr )) {
                $lt_found = false;
                $cx = 0;

                while ($cx < count( $letters_groups )) {
                    if (in_array( utf8_substr( strtoupper( $data['name'] ), 0, 1 ), $letters_groups[$cx] )) {
                        $data_arr[$cx][] = $data;
                        $lt_found = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    ++$cx;
                }

                if (!$lt_found) {
                    $data_arr2[] = $data;
                }
            }

            unset( $data );
            $cy = 0;

            while ($cy < count( $letters_groups )) {
                $data_arr_main = $data_arr[$cy];

                if (count( $data_arr_main )) {
                    print '<span align=right class=title>' . $letters_groups_names[$cy] . '</span><hr class=separate_line 1px" size="1">';
                    print '<table width=100%><tr>';
                    $c = 0;
                    foreach ($data_arr_main as $data) {

                        if ($c == $settings['songs_cells']) {
                            print '  </tr><tr>';
                            $c = 0;
                        }

                        print '<td>';
                        run_template( 'browse_singers' );
                        print '</td>';
                        ++$c;
                    }

                    print '</tr></table>';
                }

                ++$cy;
            }

            unset( $data );

            if (count( $data_arr2 )) {
                print '<span align=right class=title>' . $phrases['singers_other_letters'] . '</span><hr class=separate_line size="1">';
                print '<table width=100%><tr>';
                $c = 0;
                foreach ($data_arr2 as $data) {

                    if ($c == $settings['songs_cells']) {
                        print '  </tr><tr>';
                        $c = 0;
                    }

                    print '<td>';
                    run_template( 'browse_singers' );
                    print '</td>';
                    ++$c;
                }

                print '</tr></table>';
            }

            unset( $data );
        } else {
            print '<table width=100%><tr>';

            while ($data = db_fetch( $qr )) {
                if ($c == $settings['songs_cells']) {
                    print '  </tr><TR>';
                    $c = 0;
                }

                ++$c;
                print '<td>';
                run_template( 'browse_singers' );
                print '</td>';
            }

            print '</tr></table>';
        }

        close_table(  );
    } else {
        open_table( $title );
        print '<center>  ' . $phrases['err_no_singers'] . ' </center>';
        close_table(  );
    }

    if (( $settings['prev_next_cat'] && !$letter )) {
        prev_next_cat( $id );
    }
}

compile_hook( 'singers_end' );
require( CWD . '/includes/framework_end.php' );
 ?>
```

Все запросы выполняются но только выводит одну запись. Проблема, кажется, в этом цикле

```
while ($cy < count( $letters_groups )) {
```

Comment: @fikos, у вас тут слишком много кода и логических развилок, чтобы сказать что-то толком. Постарайтесь отследить, какой запрос выполняется и что именно он возвращает.

Comment: @fikos, если вам кажется, что вы знаете, где ошибка, посмотрите, как ведет себя программа в том месте и что там лежит в переменных. Я же по этому поводу вообще ничего ен могу сказать, потому что в этой портянке $letters_groups даже не задается.

Comment: Так как у вас в коде множество не определенных переменных, пожалуйста сообщите, какой именно запрос вызывает проблемы? А еще лучше приведите значения всех необходимых переменных, чтобы можно было проследить логику выполнения скрипта.